# Add Text to Field Programmatically (On Button Click)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I would like to know how to add text to a field (Edit text in particular) upon pressing a button? My button is on the same activity as the field if that makes any difference. I have tried append() insert() and setText() methods to insert the text to the field (it is stored in a String object on the java activity file). Nothing happens at all when I use any of the methods.

My current code is

```
public void method1(View view) {
String string = ("text");
EditText editor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditor);
editor.setText(string);
}
```

My XML

```
<Button onClick = "method1"
Text = "text"
Layout_height = "wrap_content"
Layout_width = "match_parent"/>
```

I want to do something like
   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207413/how-do-i-add-text-from-an-edittext-field-to-different-textviews-in-android-studi)
question, but I want to insert text to the field, not create extra textviews/views.

Comment: Are you sure that you mentioned method1 in onClick attribute of that button? in xml

Comment: I am certain. It's on the xml

Comment: I think is necessary more information, could you be show your XML and your activity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to add your method in your xml inside you Button Tag Like This.Here method1 is your function name.add attribute  android:onClick="method1" inside your button you can see below

```
              <Button
               android:id="@+id/btn_attach"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_45dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".4"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_bg5"
                android:onClick="method1"
                 />
```

Comment: then try to debug that your method is called or not on button click it should work

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, Change the text color in your Edit text , may be it is same as the background color.This is how the XML should be make sure all the attributes have Android namespace Prefix.

```
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/myEditor"
                android:textColor="@color/quantum_black_100"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="method1"/>
```

Will have to see the xml if this not issue